# Screen Layout for Samsung Galaxy S (480 x 854) Problem

Tags: android, screen, dpi

Does anyone know how I should layout my app for phones with the same screen as the Samsung. My app displays perfectly on small and normal densitys but for some reason the buttons are slightly higher on hdpi screens and I have to tap above them to get them to work... its very annoying.

Im trying to find out what the DPI size etc is so I can adjust it but im not having any luck... any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should post your XML layout file so we can see what you have. You shouldn't be having issues like that if you're setting up your layouts correctly, but you can set up different versions of your layout for hdpi, mdpi and ldpi devices.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S has 800×480 screen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S